# EditText editable but getText() return empty string

Tags: android

I'm trying to make a simple messaging system in my app. The user type the message in an `EditText`at the bottom of the screen. Somehow, the `EditText`that's displayed on the screen isn't actually the one that I get using `findViewById()`.

I tried adding default value to the `EditText`in the xml and it works. But if I change the default text, the text on the screen changes but `editText.getText()`still returns the default value. `editText.setText()` doesn't change the text displayed on the screen but does change the actual value (`editText.getText()` returns the new text).

Here's my code:

fragment_message.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.gloriovin.helpio.Views.MessageFragment"
    android:id="@+id/message_fragment"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sendMessageSection"
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:divider="@color/Transparent"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"></ListView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:id="@+id/sendMessageSection"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/LightGrey">

        <com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/sendButton"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            app:iiv_size="25dp"
            app:iiv_color="@color/DarkGrey"
            app:iiv_icon="gmd-send" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/messageField"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/sendButton"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="kuda"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
            android:gravity="bottom"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

chatActivity.java

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

import com.gloriovin.helpio.R;

public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar toolbar;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);
        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Message");

        MessageFragment messageFragment = new MessageFragment();
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment, messageFragment).    commit();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_message, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

messageFragment.java

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.gloriovin.helpio.Adapters.friendAdapters;
import com.gloriovin.helpio.Adapters.messageAdapters;
import com.gloriovin.helpio.Globals;
import com.gloriovin.helpio.HelpioApp;
import com.gloriovin.helpio.Models.Message;
import com.gloriovin.helpio.Models.MessageRoom;
import com.gloriovin.helpio.R;
import com.mikepenz.iconics.view.IconicsImageView;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

import cz.msebera.android.httpclient.Header;
import io.paperdb.Paper;


public class MessageFragment extends Fragment {
    private Activity activity;
    private int mid;
    public MessageFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mid = getActivity().getIntent().getIntExtra("mid", -1);
        this.activity  = getActivity();
        Log.e("mid", String.valueOf(mid));
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);



        ListView listView = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.listView);
        messageAdapters adapter = new messageAdapters(getActivity(), FAKECHAT);
        listView.setDivider(null);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


        IconicsImageView sendButton = (IconicsImageView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.    sendButton);
        sendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                EditText newMessage = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.messageField);
                String msg = newMessage.getText().toString();
                Log.e("message is", "asd"+msg);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
    }
}
```

TLDR:
in `messageFragment.java`, the `EditText` value(.getText()) is different (empty string "") than what actually typed in the `EditText`. 
`setText()`doesn't change the appearance of the `EditText`but does change the result of `getText()`

Comment: Define EditText before sendButton.setOnClickListener() and check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here:

```
EditText newMessage = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.messageField);
```

Probably getting `NPE Exception`  because `newMessage` is `null`.

`EditText` with `messageField` is inside `fragment_message` layout which is layout of Fragment. so use `getView` method for initializing `newMessage` object instead of `getActivity()` which return the Context of Activity in which Fragment is current available.

override `onViewCreated` and initialize all views using `v.findViewById` :

```
ListView listView;
IconicsImageView sendButton;
EditText newMessage;
public void onViewCreated(View v, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(v, savedInstanceState);
    listView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    sendButton = (IconicsImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.    sendButton);
    newMessage = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.messageField);
}
```

Comment: This solves the problem! Thanks a lot!

I tried something very similar to Keshav 's solution but it wasn't working.

Comment: I just noticed it raises another problem. It seems there are two EditText in my fragment eventhough i have only one in the XML. When the activity starts, the EditText gets focus and I can type without any changes in the appearance and can click on the send button and have the message actually send. Do you happen to know what might causes this? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Write this line, outside of your click listener

```
EditText newMessage = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.messageField);
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. ρяσѕρєя 's has the explanation why using getActivity() to get the EditText doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You are not fetching EditText properly.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_message, container, false);
    newMessage = (EditText) mView.findViewById(R.id.messageField);

    String msg = newMessage.getText().toString();
    return mView;
}
```

Comment: I tried something very similar to your solution but it wasn't working. ρяσѕρєя 's solution works perfectly though.

Thanks anyway